# Cuda shared memory bug

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I have this simple radix sort (it only sort by a bit and only one block). My first version works, but I tried to sort the keys on the shared memory first to achieve coalesced memory writes to DRAM. However this version produces bad results, it doesn't sort.

First, simple, working version:

```
__global__ void dev_radix(unsigned int *in_keys, const unsigned int *histo, unsigned int desp, unsigned int *out_keys){
int tid=threadIdx.x;

//Get offset by using prefix sum scan.
__shared__ unsigned int s_sum[1024];
unsigned int first=((in_keys[tid]>>desp)&1)==0;
s_sum[tid]=first;
__syncthreads();
int pos=tid-1;
for (int off=1; pos>=0; off=off*2, pos=tid-off){
    int a=s_sum[pos];
    int b=s_sum[tid];
    __syncthreads();
    s_sum[tid]=a+b;
}
__syncthreads();

int offset=s_sum[tid]-first;
if (first==0){
    //Get offset for '1' bit keys
    offset=histo[0]+tid-offset;
}

out_keys[offset]=in_keys[tid];
```

}

Second version:

```
__global__ void dev_radix(unsigned int *in_keys, const unsigned int *histo, unsigned int desp, unsigned int *out_keys){
int tid=threadIdx.x;

//Get offset by using prefix sum scan.
__shared__ unsigned int s_sum[1024];
unsigned int first=((in_keys[tid]>>desp)&1)==0;
s_sum[tid]=first;
__syncthreads();
int pos=tid-1;
for (int off=1; pos>=0; off=off*2, pos=tid-off){
    int a=s_sum[pos];
    int b=s_sum[tid];
    __syncthreads();
    s_sum[tid]=a+b;
}
__syncthreads();

int offset=s_sum[tid]-first;
if (first==0){
    //Get offset for '1' bit keys
    offset=histo[0]+tid-offset;
}

__syncthreads();
s_sum[offset]=in_keys[tid];
__syncthreads();
out_keys[tid]=s_sum[tid];
```

}

Comment: It is going to be very hard to say what might be wrong with your code without a complete repro case and a more concrete description of your problem then " doesn't sort "

Comment: I'm not a Cuda expert, but this is a 4 line difference problem, I don't think this is too diffucult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling __syncthreads() on a conditional code. It is only allowed to call __syncthreads() on conditinal code that has the same execution path for all threads in the block.
Correct version:

```
__global__ void dev_radix(unsigned int *in_keys, const unsigned int *histo, unsigned int desp, unsigned int *out_keys){
__shared__ unsigned int s_sum[1024];
int tid=threadIdx.x;

//Get offset by using prefix sum scan.
unsigned int v=in_keys[tid];
unsigned int first=((v>>desp)&1)==0;
s_sum[tid]=first;
__syncthreads();
int pos=tid-1;
for (int off=1; off<1024;){
    int a,b;
    if (pos>=0){
        a=s_sum[pos];
        b=s_sum[tid];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (pos>=0){
        s_sum[tid]=a+b;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    off=off*2;
    pos=tid-off;
}
__syncthreads();

int offset=s_sum[tid]-first;
if (first==0){
    //Get offset for '1' bit keys
    offset=histo[0]+tid-offset;
}
__syncthreads();
s_sum[offset]=v;
__syncthreads();
out_keys[tid]=s_sum[tid];
```

}